# How to change DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP format

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

Currently i am using the following code to create a table in mysql.

`CREATE TABLE example(id INT, ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`
 so whenever i insert data into this table i get the value of ts  in (YEAR-MONTH-DATE HOURS-MINUTE-SECOND) format and i want to change it in  (DATE-MONTH-YEAR HOURS-MINUTE-SECOND) , lets suppose i have inserted data in above created table by using

`insert into example (id) values (123);`
when i retrieve the information by using

`select * from example;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
|  123 | 2014-07-28 17:17:10 |
+------+---------------------+`
i get the datetime in this format `2014-07-28 17:17:10` , i want to change this to `28-07-2014 17:17:10` , Is it possible to change format of timestamp? If yes then how do we do it ?

Answer (score 5):

You should format ts output, for example:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(ts, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') FROM example
```

Here's what you need to understand. A `TIMESTAMP` data type has a well-defined internal format. That internal format is designed so MySQL can search and manipulate it easily. (It's a variant of the UNIX/Linux `time_t` datatype, if you care.) You can't change that format.

When you ask MySQL to render a timestamp it displays it using the default format shown in your question.  What you CAN do is format it for display, like the example in this answer demonstrates.

Comment: can i use SELECT id,name, DATE_FORMAT(ts, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') FROM example, in case if i have name field

Comment: @user3202044, did you try that? It will definitely work.